# How to fix undefined map variable?

Tags: angular, google-maps, cordova, ionic4

Currently working on a ionic 4 mobile application I've to add a map to interact with. When I launch the application, the loading is working fine but when I want to interact with the map in other methods than the loading one, my variable is undefined.

You'll see in this part the two services that are concerned in the problem.
To sum up, when I launch the app, I call the loadMap() function and after thath I call the addMarker() method.

It's in this method that my variable map is undefined and I don't understand why.

This is the service that call the addMarker() method

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { getRandomString } from 'selenium-webdriver/safari';
import {Marker, MarkerOptions} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';
import {MapService} from './map.service';
const  GlobalIcon = 'compass';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IndiceService {
  public indices: Array<{ title: string; note: any; icon: string, id: number, lat:number, lng:number }> = [];
  constructor(private router: Router, private map : MapService) { }


  ajouterIndice(passedNote:any){ //Faire cet ajout à l'aide d'une promesse ???
    this.indices.push({
      title : 'Indice ' + (this.indices.length+1),
      note : passedNote,
      icon : GlobalIcon,
      id : this.indices.length+1,
      lat: this.getRandomInt(45,75),
      lng: this.getRandomInt(4,5),
    });

    this.map.addMarker(this.indices.length,this.indices[this.indices.length-1].note,this.indices[this.indices.length-1].lat,this.indices[this.indices.length-1].lng);
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }

  isIndiceIncluded(data :any) : boolean{
    return this.indices.find(x => x.note === data) != undefined;
  }

  getRandomInt(min, max) : number {
    return Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min;
  }

}
```

This service is my map service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  GoogleMaps,
  GoogleMap,
  GoogleMapsEvent,
  GoogleMapOptions,
  CameraPosition,
  MarkerOptions,
  Marker,
  Environment
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MapService {

  private map: GoogleMap;
  public markers : Array<Marker> = [];

  constructor() { }

  loadMap() {
    let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
      camera: {
         target: {
           lat: 43.783125,
           lng: 2.809419
         },
         zoom: 18,
         tilt: 30
       }
    };

    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map', mapOptions);

    let marker: Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync({
      title: 'Ionic',
      icon: 'red',
      animation: 'DROP',
      position: {
        lat: 45.783125,
        lng: 4.809419
      },
    });
     /*marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe(() => {
      alert('clicked');
    });*/
  }

  addMarker(id : number ,note : any, lat:number, lng:number){

    console.log(this.map); //write undefined

    let currentMarker : Marker = this.map.addMarkerSync({
      id : id,
      title: note,
      icon: 'red',
      animation: 'DROP',
      position: {
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
      },
    });

    this.markers.push(currentMarker);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help and sorry for my english level.

Comment: when u type this.map. does it show addmarker method name?

Comment: Yes this method is availible.

Comment: your this.map gets value when loadmap() is executed.But when u try to use the method addmarker() directly it will show undefined

Comment: That's why I don't understand because loadmap() is necesseraly called before addMarker() ...

Comment: add  this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map', mapOptions); inside addmarker() method also and see if it works

Comment: It works but the marker IS not visible x)

Comment: add this let mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
      camera: {
         target: {
           lat: 43.783125,
           lng: 2.809419
         },
         zoom: 18,
         tilt: 30
       }
    }; above this.map in addmarker

Comment: I've made a constant mapOptions inside m'y service, I Wonder if the map from loadmap is still showed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try to load the map, in your MapService, after the platform is ready

```
constructor(private platform: Platform) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.loadMap();
    });
}
```

**EDIT** :

This is a sample code which is working for me;

```
import { AfterContentInit, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
declare var google;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage implements AfterContentInit {
  @ViewChild('mapElement') mapElement;
  map:any;
  latitude: any = 22.454453;
  longitude: any = 88.389610;

  constructor() {}
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    const pos = { lat: this.latitude, lng: this.longitude };
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(
      this.mapElement.nativeElement, {
        center: { lat: this.latitude, lng: this.longitude }, zoom: 17
      });
    this.map.setCenter(pos);
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
        position: pos, /* marker position */ 
        map: this.map, /* map already created */ 
        title: 'Hello World!'});
    const  contentString = '<div id="content"><h1>Amitabh</h1><div id="bodyContent"><p>Is a good person, I must select his answer and upvote him</p></div>';

    const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
        content: contentString, maxWidth: 400 });
    marker.addListener('click', function() { 
          infowindow.open(this.map, marker);
    });

  }
}
```

Hope this helps Screenshot running using ***ionic serve -col***
[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'll try now.


For more information, when I call addMarker into home.page.ts, the page with map div in the html part it work perfectly.

But when I call addMarker in indiceService, wich is an element with no HTML the map is "undefined", like it was loose

Comment: Wow, it works ! Thanks a lot :D

I've to admit that I don't know why it doesn't work before, because I don't have Platform into my map.service ?

What is the purpose of this element ?

Comment: In fact my problem is not resolved :(

I discovered that when I call loadMap() after the first call of addMarker it work, but if I call loadMap in the constructor I don't have any undefined problems but markers will be invisible :/

Comment: The main issue is the timing, your codes were being called before the map library was loaded into the memory and is ready for rendering. I just delayed the loadMap until the platform is ready. I am sure if you look properly into your codes, and sequence it properly, it will work. I have a delivery to make and possibly will try to cook up a sample code for your reference later in the day (:p don't hold your breath please)

Comment: You are the best :D I will continue to search, thanks for your help !

Comment: I think my main problem is, sometimes, depends on where I called the MapService I got this message "Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Can not find the element [#map]"

Comment: I have updated the answer with sample code, it basically initializes the map in the _AfterContentInit_ ( _ngAfterContentInit()_ ). After the map is loaded, I create InfoWindow for showing information, and then finally add the marker and its click event (to show InfoWindow). You can customize this icon using the **png** attribute (with a relative path to a custom marker image) if required.  If you notice, I have called the various functions in a sequence which is the key to initiate and show the map and its elements. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !

I upvote your post now !